# Send Image in Dialogflow Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

How would I send an image in Dialogflow using NodeJS? I want it to work on any platform, but for now, Telegram is fine. When I try this code I get this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unknown response type: "{}".
Note: I am not using the inline editor.

```
const myPicture = new Image({
                    imageURL: picture
                });
agent.add(myPicture);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing the `platform:` parameter to send a picture via Telegram using the `Image()` class. Include `platform: 'TELEGRAM'` to specify where you are integrating the message.  Initialize the object at `agent.add()` by calling `new Image(anotherImage)`

For reference here are the available [key value pair for platforms](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/86a844a34ce61a665fa3687afe91af68b3dca0b8/src/rich-responses/rich-response.js#L17). See code below:

```
const imageUrl = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg/200px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png';
const anotherImage = new Image({
            imageUrl: imageUrl,
            platform: 'TELEGRAM'
       });
        
agent.add(new Image(anotherImage));
```

Test run:

[image]

There are other sample code implementations as seen [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/tree/86a844a34ce61a665fa3687afe91af68b3dca0b8#samples). A useful example for using an image is found in this [Git repository](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-temperature-converter-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js#L130).